# Speeding up Python Tkinter Program

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I have programmed an App with Tkinter on Python, that reads out a number of consecutive XML-protocols of a (literary) writing process and visualizes the same process in a Tkinter Text widget. The program is already working, a video version of the result can be watched here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3q8F8SEc68

In the video posted, I recorded a screen video and speeded up the video. Now, however, I want to be able to speed up the process on program-level. Goal is, as in the video, to synchronzie the whole process with a reading of the - naturally much shorter - product, but live, this time.

Somehow I can't seem to get the program to be running more quickly and am wondering, which is the limiting factor here. I have ruled out XML-parsing as the reason by separating parsing and visualization. In this first step the XML-files are rearranged into a list of dictionaries. An example:

```
chain_of_events = [...,
{'type': 'input',
'value': 'h',
'delay': 254,
'position': 648},
{'type': 'input',
'value': 'e',
'delay': 542,
'position': 649},
{'type': 'cursor',
'delay': 928,
'position': 648},
{'type': 'input',
'value': 'T',
'delay': 542,
'position': 648}, ...]
```

In the second step this list is processed to rearrange the writing-process. This is done mostly via a single function `process()`, that calls itself repeatedly. It is not practical to post all of the (messy) code here, I will instead focus on the part, that does the actual writing:

```
def process():
    global chain_of_events
    if chain_of_events != []:
        action = chain_of_events.pop(0)
        delay = action["delay"]
        if action["type"] == "cursor":
            if txt.tag_ranges(tk.SEL):
                txt.tag_remove(tk.SEL, tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)   #remove existing selections
            txt.mark_set("insert", "1.0 + %d chars" % (action["position"])) #set cursor position

        elif action["type"] == "delete":
            txt.delete("1.0 + %d chars" % (action["start"]), "1.0 + %d chars" % (action["end"]))  #deletion
            txt.mark_set("insert", "1.0 + %d chars" % (action["start"]))  #set cursor position
       
        elif action["type"] == "input":
            txt.insert("insert", action["value"])  #input text

        window.after(delay, process())  #rinse and repeat


# main program

window = tkinter.Tk()
txt = tkinter.Text(window)
process()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are so many things that can impact the speed at which your program runs. From your import statements to the computer that you run it on.  Aside from adjusting the speed variable, what have you tried? Maybe you can use the timeit module and experiment with rewriting parts of the code like minimizing for loops, using list comprehension and even look into multiprocessing or threading if appropriate.

Comment: do you really need to use `after()`? Besides `after` needs function's name without `()` and later arguments -  like `after(time, Text.insert, "1.0 + %d chars" % (Position), Value)` - so your code first run `Text.insert()` and get its result `None` and later it runs `Window.after(int(Delay / SPEED), None)`. Maybe you should try without `after()`

Comment: BTW: there is good rule: `lower_case_names` for variables and `CamelCaseNames` for classes. It helps to recognize class in code. So it would be more readable if you would use `window`, `text`, `tree`, `root`, `events`, `event`, `position`, `value`, `delay`. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: some IDEs have tool called `Profiler` which may show which functions use more time - and then you can see which function may need changes. Or you could use `time` or `timeit` to measure time.

Comment: @furas I need ```after()``` to preserve the writing speed of the original process, so that each insertion of text into the widget is delayed correspondingly to the original button-press. I just want to be able to speed the original delays up by an integer. If there is an alternative way to do that without ```after()```, I'm game! In the original code, ```after()```calls a function, that inserts the text, so this works fine in the original. Fixed the variables also, thx for the hint!

Comment: maybe first check what values you get wiht `int(Delay / SPEED)`, And if you want to keep original speed then why you divide by 100. But first you should measure time for other elements - maybe problem is not `after()` but parsing `XML`.

Comment: @furas the values I get are fine. (Exemplary) division by 100 is the speed-up I want, but which I don't get. Each action of writing to the tkinter widget takes about 50ms. I have rearranged the program in such a way, that parsing is done beforehand. No real speed increase, the parsing section of the program takes about 2 seconds for all of the XML files. I will rewrite the question and try to include the actual code...

Comment: Python is slow language - and `tkinter` doesn't access widget directly but it converts code to language `tcl/tk` and run it. Maybe you will have to use other frameworks - like `PyQt` which uses `Qt` created in C/C++

Comment: when I run without `after()` then average time for single loop is `~10ms` (but first loop can get ~75ms` and some may get only ~2ms). When you use ie. `after(20)` then it doesn't have to wait `exactly 20ms` but `at least 20ms` (but it may wait longer if other elements on system need CPU) - and the same is with `time.sleep()`

Comment: @furas Thank you for taking the trouble. I am stuck near about 50ms for one loop with text input *without delay*.

Comment: All this if, else condition checks takes time. Why not use a tuple of 4 values and iter() throw the lines.